# JavaScript not running when publishing my asp.net.core 2.0 app to IIS

Tags: javascript, c#, iis, asp.net-core, publishing

I am a newbie here. I have a VS2017 asp.net C# web app. I am not using Angular at this stage. It is a simple site.

I hide divs and when a user clicks on a menu item the div relevant appears and I hide the rest of the divs. I use JavaScript to accomplish this.

In development and IIS Express it works. When I publish to IIS it does not work. The static page displays OK but the menu button do not do anything.

If I press F12 I can see there are no errors. I can also see if I press Network tab that my site.js script does not seem to be loaded.

I looked at the Environment tags (not sure how to see these for release/publish - would love to see a link for better documentation that tells me directly how to use).

In desperation I removed all the environment tags relating to my JS files.  I know this is not the correct way to do things, I am just trying to locate the problem area.

To simplify things even further I put an `alert("hi")` directly into my JS file so it should pop up when I visit the site but it does not.

This is my _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 101%">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @*<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Informed Products</a>*@
                <a id="InformedServices" style="cursor: pointer" class="navbar-brand">Informed Services</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @*<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>*@
                    @*<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>*@



                    <li><a id="HowWeWork" style="cursor: pointer">How We Work</a></li>
                    <li><a id="Pricing" style="cursor: pointer">Adaptive Pricing Service</a></li>
                    <li><a id="About" style="cursor: pointer">About</a></li>
                    <li><a id="ContactUs" style="cursor: pointer">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018 - Informed Services</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @*<environment include="Development,Production">*@
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @*</environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">*@
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @*</environment>*@

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In my site.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert("b");

});
```

### Update

I have found that on the server, `site.js` looks OK, but `site.min.js` is empty. What might be the cause of that?

Comment: Have you tried any JS on console of the browser after being hosted on IIS server?

Comment: Hi thanks for taking mercy on me :). That is a good idea. I will give that a go when back in.  What should I do if it a). Does not work b). Dies work? Thanks

Comment: When you say that your script doesn't appear to be loaded does it mean you get a 404 when the browser request /js/site.min.js ? has this file been correctly deployed on the iis server?

Comment: If it is not loading there is only one explanation it is not loaded to the browser, if you are using chrome, open the developer option select the source tab, in the top left select Network and see if your script is loaded on the page, another option is to reload your page while the console is up, then check the network tab and see if there is a 404 for your script. Hope this helps.

Comment: @EmmanuelAmodu Thansk for your comment. But I did say I did all that in my question. This is why I am confused

Comment: @halfer thanks for your comment.  I have looked under network and I can see that site.min.js is loaded but not site.js. There is nothing inside site.min.js.

Comment: @halfer I had removed the environment tags in my markup should that not bypass all that?

Comment: @Narwen Hi tried alert("hi") in console tab. That all works.

Comment: "There is nothing inside site.min.js" - I guess that is your problem, then. Why is there nothing inside this? How are you transferring your files to this server? Is the file not empty when sitting on the disk in this server?

Comment: @halfer I had thought all this  is done automatically when i do a publish via vs2017.  I do not know how this file is created. When I look in my solution it is not there. I did say I was a newbie :(

Comment: @halfer I am working with RDP.  I have the solution on my server and i publish it to a seperate folder and I point IIS directory to tha published folder

Comment: @halfer looking at that file on the published directory i can see the file exists but is empty. The site.js is there and not empty

Comment: Right. So perhaps minification is broken - are there any logs/warnings when you publish? You may need to check some logs on your dev machine. Also, could the minification happen on the server? (I don't use Microsoft or .net, so this is all guesswork).

Comment: @halfer nothin gin logs that I can see. But at least i got something new to Google upon. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your minification process is broken for the `site.js` file. As a stopgap, you could change your website to use the full version, assuming you don't mind people seeing the original source code.

To do this, change the following line to refer to `site.js` instead:

```
<script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

I would recommend you still look for why minification is failing in your case.

Comment: Thanks was learning curve. Brings me breathing space. Can look into why this happened later. thanks

Comment: Great. Don't let the site/product owners ignore the problem permanently though - problems that are ignored have a tendency to balloon if left untreated! Developers sometimes have to lobby hard to get refactoring/improvement time, but it is worth it.

Comment: Agreed. that was why I like to do things the correct way. But things like this happen to me all to frequently lol

Comment: Hi @dfi: it is quite normal to make that sort of edit here. The canonical guidance is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/472495), and there's another one as well - hang on.

Comment: @halfer Well, halfer, I appreciate your enormous effort. But I will still keep my thank yous until someone complains about it.

Comment: @dfi: another guidance post [is this one here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/472495), which reflects some of our 'editing culture' on Stack Overflow. Of course, if you'd like to come to Meta to support chatty material, politenesses and niceties, you are welcome to do that, but I don't think it is going to be popular. It does come up from time to time, and I am happy to respond to the suggestion there as required.

Comment: From my boilerplate advice items: _Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened_.

Comment: This one is [the latest complaint](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367981/to-edit-or-not-to-edit) on Meta - a high rep user appears to have gone on strike over the issue. But, we cannot please everyone, and the community remains in support of "fluff removal".